# Scheduled functions with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, push-notification, google-cloud-functions, sequelize.js

I currently have a NodeJS backend, Postgres DB and sequelize as my ORM. I have a transactions table in my db that stores the date of the transactions in YYYY-MM-DD format. I would like to notify the users with a notification when the date of the transaction is todays date.

I got recommended to use a cron task that runs once a day, that searchs the date column of my transaction table to dates that are equal to todays date then send an expo push notification to the users with transaction due today to make a payment.

I tried doing so with google cloud functions but for some reason, the function is not getting deployed.

My question: Is what i am doing even possible in terms scheduling a google cloud function to search from entries in my postgres db?

Here is my cloud function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const moment = require('moment');
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { Expo } = require("expo-server-sdk");
const sendPushNotification = require("../utilities/pushNotifications");
const PushToken = require("../models/Pushtoken");
const Product = require("../models/Products");
const Order = require("../models/Orders");
const Transaction = require("../models/Transactions");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json())

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions
.pubsub
.schedule('00 11 * * *')
    .onRun(async(context) => {

    const now = moment();
    const dateFormatted = now.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

    const today =[];

    const transactionDueToday = await Transaction.findAll({
        where:{
            date:dateFormatted
        },
        include: [
            { model: Order, attributes: ["id", "ProductId"],
                include: [
                    { model: Product, attributes: ["id", "title"] },
                ]
            },
            { model: PushToken, attributes: ["id", "token"] },
          ],
    })

    transactionDueToday.map((x)=>{
        today.push({user:x.userId,token:x.PushToken.token,productTitle:x.Order.Product.title})
    })

    functions.logger.log(today);

    // send notification to these id's reminding then

});
```

The code above does not include sending notification.

Answer (score 1):

A google cloud function can do what ever you write in the function.

If the function environment has the required access to your DB, then it should be able to run the queries and do what ever you need with the results.

It looks like your NodeJS server doesn't run on Google, I'm assuming the DB is local too. You don't need a cloud function at all, you can set the schedule task on your own server, access your own DB, then sending firebase the push requests only.

Comment: Hi, and thank you for getting back to me. Yes, i am currently in development phase hence my db and backend are run locally. 1) How to i schedule a task on my own server 2) i need to give firebase access to my database in order to query ?

Comment: 1. cronjob on linux, Schedule Tasks on windows. 2. If you run query on your own local machine you don't need to give firebase any access to your database. if you run a query on firebase function - the database should be accessible from google.

Comment: For some reason, when i try deploying the cloud function i keep getting ```Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module '../models/Pushtoken'``` and i am sure import is correct

Comment: Why are you insist to deploy the function? It won't work anyway. Google cloud does not have access to your local db.

Comment: Is it possible to give google cloud access to my postgres db deployed on google cloud?

Comment: Also, at the moment everything is running locally for testing purpose, but very soon i will be deploying and hence why i asking about google cloud.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but it is way out of scope.